# Generate Unique IV in Angular and Decrypt In C#

Tags: c#, angular, aes

Is there parallel to Rijnadel GenerateIV in cryptojs?
Or I should create myself same algorithm for creating IV.
Is there a standard for creating IV?
What is usually done?
Using the message data or just creating algorithm( same one) in server and client

Thanks

Comment: The IV must be shared. It's not a password, it's just the initial data. `message data` that's a completely different story - there are specific messaging protocols that handle this. What are you trying to do? Creating your own custom protocol is *not* a good idea. Nor is hand-written encryption of requests. That's what HTTPS is for and works better than hand-written encryption. You can use TLS 1.3 with AES and very long hashes just by changing some settings on the server